Wallet Drained Without Transaction approval
My telegram  wallet was drained after depositing sol without  using transaction approval have been using  it for trading the address 9aQddgsYYeKkjXuHYRjxfE8gWwvTeuHxFBNKZBkcyrs7
And the associted address is 9NoAK8h1QnMHQ9gkyyivpGGk3qHjBFt9mfyNw6tiLHwL. I checked for any approvals but I didn't  have any reason  has to why and what I can do to avoid future attacks

9NoAK8h1QnMHQ9gkyyivpGGk3qHjBFt9mfyNw6tiLHwL
I had the same wallet steal from me. I was using a trade wiz bot that I had no issues with then all of a sudden the bot didn’t work
